# Jenkins rejects LinkedHashMap in system groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In our Jenkins environment we still have some old freestyle jobs which we do not want to change to pipelines. One of those uses a system groovy script. This week we decided to upgrade the Jenkins version to 2.46 (also updated plugin, e.g. security) and all of the sudden the system groovy script didn't work anymore

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectNew(StaticWhitelist.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:188)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedConstructor$3.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:214)
    at DescriptionPriorities.<init>(Script1.groovy)
    at DescriptionPriorities.$INIT(Script1.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:177)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedStaticCall$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)
    at DescriptionPriorities.<clinit>(Script1.groovy)
Caused: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedField.getProperty(CachedField.java:54)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1805)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:243)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:350)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:230)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.run(GroovySandbox.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:165)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

For pipelines I can go to "manage Jenkins" and approve the script, but usually I approve a script as a whole or whitelist some method signatures. But I never had to approve the use of an object. Also the script approval page has nothing pending.

Can I somehow add this to the approval list or simply ignore it? Maybe somehow modify the scriptApproval.xml directly?

script-security plugin has version 1.27 if relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the already given answer is correct, it was really annoying to always change the xml file directly. After the 2nd fix that still failed I tried something else. Instead of loading the file from GIT i put system groovy code directly into the job and loaded the file myself:

```
evaluate(new File("path/to/file"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this situation several times and added the signature manually to the `scriptApproval.xml`.

Add `new java.util.LinkedHashMap` to approvedSignatures:

```
 <approvedSignatures>
    <string>new java.util.LinkedHashMap</string>
 </approvedSignatures>
```

I don't know why this happens, I consider it as a bug.